# Cut values to intervals and plot a heatmap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L), quater = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), value = c(4L, 23L, 14L, 
12L, 6L, 22L, 45L, 12L, 34L, 15L, 3L, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Out:

```
    year  quater  value
0   2001       1      4
1   2001       2     23
2   2001       3     14
3   2001       4     12
4   2002       1      6
5   2002       2     22
6   2002       3     45
7   2002       4     12
8   2003       1     34
9   2003       2     15
10  2003       3      3
11  2003       4     40
```

How could I plot a chart similar to the plot below:

[image]

Please note the `year` and `quater` in this dataset correspondent to `year` and `week` to the plot above.

I need to first `cut` the `value` column by `(0, 10], (10, 20], (20, 30], (30, 40], (40, 50]` then plot them.

The code I have tried:

```
ggplot(df, aes(week, year, fill= value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red")
```

Out:

[image]

As you can see, the legend is different to what I need.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add `df %>% mutate(value = cut(value, seq(0, 50, 10)))` before `ggplot` ?

Comment: Could you post the complete code in the answer pls?

Comment: I was suggesting `df %>% mutate(value = cut(value, seq(0, 50, 10))) %>% ggplot() + aes(quater, year, fill = value) + geom_tile()` . `scale_fill_gradient` does not work with factors though.

Comment: Yeah, the legend seems not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first use `cut` to get the classes (as Ronak Shah already mentioned) and then you can use `scale_fill_brewer` to change the color of the tiles.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(class = cut(value, seq(0, 50, 10))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(quater, year, fill = class) ) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq",
                    direction = 1,
                    palette = "RdPu")
```

[image: Tile plot]